# What is the hybridization of the carbon atom in cyclopropenyl carbocation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, carbocation

The hybridization of the carbocation in the cyclopropenyl carbocation (which is aromatic) should be sp as it as the + and also is in a ring. But the carbocation has a sp2 hybridization, why?

For example, a phenyl carbocation has a hybridization sp.

Thank you!

Comment: I have a feeling you'd better forget what you think you know about phenyl carbocation, and start learning about hybridization from beginning.

Comment: @Mithoron So I tried explaining it to myself via the vsepr theory, which gives me a sp2 configuration for the C with +ve charge in cyclopropenyl carbocation. Also tried with the phenyl carbocation and turns out it's between sp and sp2. I did not understand the reason for this, but I assume the phenyl is not sp then? It would really help if you could correct me wherever I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Your "hybridization" is pretty much a post factum rationalisation depending on *geometry* which is an actual observable. For sp there has to be 180 deg angle and for sp2 it's 120, otherwise that's not it and that's the situation in both carbocations.

Comment: Not wishing to add fuel to the fire here, but the C-C orbitals within cyclopentane are often said to have "sp5" hybridization. Assuming that this remains the case in the cation, and that the cation is a "pure" p-orbital (for reasons of conjugation/aromaticity) this would imply "s2p" hybridization in the remaining C-H bond...

Answer (score 0):

The carbon with a positive charge on the cyclopropenyl carbocation is the carbon which is not involved in the double bond.

Hence, when not a carbocation, this carbon forms 4 sigma bonds, 2 with 2 different hydrogen atoms and one with each of the other two carbon atoms. It has no line pairs.

As a carbocation, this carbon atom remains bonded to the two carbons, so whatever reaction mechanism you’re looking at, the positive charge means that this carbon is now only bonded to one hydrogen.

Thus, the positive carbon forms three bonds and has 0 lone pairs, so it has a steric number of 3 (and requires three atomic orbitals).

These three atomic orbitals are thus sp2 hybridized.

Diagram explanation below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here's an answer based on how I was taught this theory.

The carbon atoms in benzene have sp2 hybridization because they are attached to three entities (two carbon atoms, one hydrogen atom, no lone pairs). Yank off an H– to create a phenyl carbocation. The carbon atom from which the H– was removed is now attached to two entities (two carbon atoms, no lone pairs) instead of three. Therefore this carbon now has an sp hybridization.

The carbon atom without a double bond in cyclopropene has sp3 hybridization because it is attached to four entities (two C atoms, two H atoms, no lone pairs). Yank off an H– from this atom to create a cyclopropenyl carbocation. It is now attached to three entities (two C atoms, one H atom, no lone pairs) instead of four. Therefore this carbon now has an sp2 hybridization.

I think teachers and students should avoid using the word "should" when describing predicted outcomes from conceptual models like orbital hybridization theory. (On the other hand, it's OK to use the word "should" when describing how language should be used!)

Comment: Your logic might work for simple tetraatomic molecules, but fails completely here, in molecules that can change the geometry of carbon skeleton only so slightly.